# Facing issue to open Macro document in Modern Browser(FF, chrome) and Export As Fixed Format, Some could help here

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Facing issue to open Macro document in Modern Browser(FF, chrome) and Export As Fixed Format.The below code user open macro document and set value as per the condition, next export it as fixed format.

```
function launch_alwaysprint (loc)
var i;
{
    var w= new ActiveXObject("Word.Application"); 
    w.Visible = true;
    w.WindowState = 2; //Minimize
    w.WindowState = 1; //Maximize
    var obj= w.documents.open(loc);

    for (i=1; i<=obj.FormFields.count; i++) {
        if (obj.FormFields(i).name == "AccountOwner") {
                        if (document.forms[0].AccountOwnerOverride.value != "") {
                            obj.FormFields(obj.FormFields(i).name).Range.Fields(1).result.text = document.forms[0].AccountOwnerOverride.value;
                        }
                        else {
                                obj.FormFields(obj.FormFields(i).name).Range.Fields(1).result.text = document.forms[0][obj.FormFields(i).name].value;
                        }
                 }
    } //End For

    obj.RunAutoMacro(2);
    //obj.Protect(1,true,"Xz123Asdf34");
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var pathToMyDocuments = shell.SpecialFolders('MyDocuments')+"\\test1.pdf"; 
    alert("Contract will be opened as a PDF but it will not be automatically saved");
    obj.ExportAsFixedFormat(pathToMyDocuments,"17","true");
    obj.Close(0)
    w.Quit(0)

} // End Main fnc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a web browser.

Launching and interacting with applications on the user's computer is a security risk, and web pages are no longer allowed to do it. (This code would only have ever worked on Internet Explorer, and even then, only on certain older versions with nonstandard security zone settings.)

You will need to find another way of doing this -- probably by processing the document and generating a PDF on the server.